# How to account for tabs in `hl-line-range-function`?

Tags: whitespace, highlighting, tabs, hl-line-mode

To avoid conflicts with highlighting indentation, I made the highlight line begin after the current indentation.

This works well, except when tabs are used as leading white space.

How could the `my-hl-line-range-function` calculate offsets taking tabs into account?

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)

;; don't draw over indentation (annoying/distracting with indent guides)
(defun my-hl-line-range-function ()
  (cons
   ;; (point)  ;; works nice too, cursor instead of indentation
   (+ (line-beginning-position 1) (current-indentation))
   (line-beginning-position 2)))
(setq hl-line-range-function #'my-hl-line-range-function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout

```
(defun my-hl-line-range-function ()
  (cons
   ;; (point)  ;; works nice too, cursor instead of indentation
   (save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (point))
   (line-beginning-position 2)))
```